# How do I keep or show a value's column name for a Pandas pivot table that has 1 or more columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

When I use Pandas to create a pivot table that includes columns, the columns in the resulting pivot that should be named the same as the value do not have a column name. In the following example, the pivot table's value is based on column C, but when the pivot table is output as text or HTML the column has no header. Is there a way to get pandas to either keep or show the column name for this column - which should be named C?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "A": ["one", "one", "two", "three"] * 3,
            "B": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar"] * 2,
            "C": np.random.randn(12),
        }
    )

pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values="C", index=["A"], columns=["B"])
print(pivot)
print(pivot.to_html())
```

The output as text is:

```
B           bar       foo
A                        
one    0.445356 -0.026072
three -0.336463 -0.717296
two    0.436955 -0.789914
```

However, I want C to be in the 2 headers for the 2 columns that contain aggregations of C, e.g. the spaces right above 0.445356 -0.026072, like this:

```
B           bar       foo
A             C         C
one    0.445356 -0.026072
three -0.336463 -0.717296
two    0.436955 -0.789914
```

The output as html is:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>B</th>
      <th>bar</th>
      <th>foo</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>one</th>
      <td>0.445356</td>
      <td>-0.026072</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>three</th>
      <td>-0.336463</td>
      <td>-0.717296</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>two</th>
      <td>0.436955</td>
      <td>-0.789914</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However I would like it to be:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>B</th>
      <th>bar</th>
      <th>foo</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>one</th>
      <td>0.445356</td>
      <td>-0.026072</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>three</th>
      <td>-0.336463</td>
      <td>-0.717296</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>two</th>
      <td>0.436955</td>
      <td>-0.789914</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Where would you expect the C header to be?

Comment: I expect it to be in the 2 headers for the 2 columns that contain aggregations of C. e.g. the spaces right above 0.445356 -0.026072. I'll edit the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try `assign` a new column

```
out = pd.pivot_table(df.assign(key='C'), values="C", index=["A"], columns=["B",'key'])
B           bar       foo
key           C         C
A                        
one    0.838796  1.029971
three  0.395790  1.192384
two   -0.583045  0.264484
```